# My C# Dynamic DLL reference is returning Value Cannot Be Null

Tags: c#, dll, dynamic

I am trying to call a DLL i created by i want to load Dynamically.

Class Definition for DLL

```
namespace pqs.Utilities
{
    public class Transform
    {
        public string ImportXMLFile(string cFileSource, string VirtDir, string cFileXSLT, string cFileDest)
        {
```

But when i call this code below I get Value cannot be null. Parameter name: type
I don't understand why ..

```
    string ClasstoInstantiate = "pqs.Utilities.pqs_util_Transform.Transform";
    Type classType = Type.GetType(ClasstoInstantiate);
    object o = Activator.CreateInstance(classType);
    string x;
    x= (string) classType.InvokeMember("ImportXMLFile",
     BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public,
     null, o, new object[]{"", "", "", ""});
```

Comment: pqs_util_Transform is the dll name pqs.Utilities is the namespace

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Type.GetType only looks in the executing and mscorlib assemblies.  It doesn't know about your `pqs_util_Transform` assembly.  You need to pass an assembly-qualified type name e.g.

```
string classToInstantiate = "pqs.Utilities.Transform, pqs_util_Transform";
                                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

where `pqs_util_Transform` is the name of the assembly (DLL) containing the Transform class.  Note that the DLL name is placed after a comma, not between the namespace and the class name which is what you seem to be doing at the moment.

See [Type.AssemblyQualifiedName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.assemblyqualifiedname.aspx) for more info about the format of assembly-qualified names especially if you need to deal with versioning, GACed assemblies, etc.

Comment: pqs_util_Transform is the dll name pqs.Utilities is the namespace

Comment: I made the changes it doesn't get rid of the null on the Type.GetType(ClasstoInstantiate); Call.  Any idea what is causing that?

Comment: Is the dynamic DLL in the application directory?  Also, try calling the overload `Type.GetType(classToInstantiate, true)`.  This will throw an exception when it fails, which you can examine in the debugger and may give you more information (e.g. FileNotFoundException means assembly not found, TypeLoadException may indicate a typo in the class name, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should first load the assembly dynamically, using the [Assembly.Load](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.load.aspx) method.  Once the assembly is loaded, you should be able to create an instance of your class.  BTW, it seems, the ClasstoInstantiate variable is wrong.  Shouldn't it be:   "pqs.Utilities.Transform, assemblyName" value?